# Python get info from long complicated string

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, split

Im trying to get info from strings that I have parsed. Im trying to get the font size. This is the string Im returning

```
style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"
```

Im trying to get `70` from `font-size` what would the best way to do that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module for the task:

```
style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"

import re

print( re.search(r'font-size:\s*(\d+)', style)[1] )
```

Prints:

```
70
```

Comment: What if I was trying to get the ```rgb``` values? I was hoping to put it into a list so I could use the rgb values some where like ```rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]```

Comment: @JackSoder Do you want to get the RGB values of `fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);`?

Comment: Yeah thats what im trying to get

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can parse the string to a dictionary. This might be useful if you want to access more than just that property.

```py
style_dict = dict([[a.strip() for a in s.split(':')] for s in style.split(';') if s != ""])
style_dict['font-size']
```

Gives

```
'70px'
```

If you don't want the units:

```
style_dict['font-size'][:-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to find what you need

```
    import re

    style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font- 
    size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"

    fontSize = re.findall("font-size: (.+)px",style)[0] # returns '70'
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: While the OP's question uses px as units, there are other valid units for font-size in CSS. This will fail in those other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.split()` method is one approach.

You can split the string into a python list to separate each kind of entry in your string. Then you can iterate though your list splitting each sub-string and save your values in a python dictionary.

```
style = "fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"
style_dict = {}
style = style.split("; ")

for item in style:
    key, value = item.split(": ")
    style_dict[key] = value

key = "font-size"
print(style_dict[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to accomplish this, but it would be better to use some package that understands CSS. Anyways, give this a try:

```py
import re


style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"
font_size = re.match(r'.*font-size: ([^;^a-z]+).*', style)
```