# From a string, how to extract values between parentheses following rgb?

Tags: python, regex

This is branching from my last post here [Python get info from long complicated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492634/python-get-info-from-long-complicated-string)

- The string is from a weird XML file I'm parsing
- I'm wondering how I can use re to get the rgb values from this string

```
style="fill: rgb(100, 2, 5); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"
```

- To use them later like:

```
print(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])
# 100 2 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) or [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)to find the pattern in the string

  - `.findall` returns an empty list if no match is found
  - `.search` returns `None` if no match is found
- Pattern explanation:

  - Following `rgb`, catches anything beteen parentheses.
  - [image]
  - [image]
  - Regular expression tested on [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/)
- Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert numbers to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

```py
import re

# string
style="fill: rgb(100, 2, 5); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"

# pattern
pattern = '(?<=rgb)\((.+)\)'

rgb = list(map(int, re.findall(pattern, style)[0].split(',')))  # assumes a match will be found.

print(rgb)
[100, 2, 5]

print(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])
100 2 5
```

### If there's a possibility of no match in the string

```py
# find the pattern
rgb = re.findall(pattern, style)

# if the list isn't empty, extract values as ints
if rgb:  
    rgb = list(map(int, rgb[0].split(',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would splice the string from the open parenthesis to the close parenthesis, and then make it a list. Something like:

```
rgb = style[style.find("(") + 1:style.find(")")].split(", ")
```

rgb will be a list: ['100' , '2' , '5']

Answer (score 1):

This works quite well and fits all situations:

```
import re
style = "fill: rgb(100, 2, 5); fill-opacity: 1; font-family: ProjectStocksFont; font-size: 70px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;"
match = re.search(r'rgb\((\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3})\)', style)
rgb = match[0].replace("rgb(","").replace(")","").strip().split(',')
```

Which gives you:

```
rgb[0]
'100'
rgb[1]
'2'
rgb[2]
'5'
```

You can then cast them as an integer or whatever you need as well.